# Pandas - fill missing times in Time-Series data

Tags: python, pandas, date, time-series

have a pandas dataframe like this:

```
    date_time    var1     var2    var3   var4    var6
20080322 0000       0        0       0      0     -11
20080322 0001       0        5       0      0       9
20080322 0003       5        0       0      0       0
20080322 0004       0        0      11      0      -9
20080322 0005       0       12       0      0       1
20080322 0009       7        0       0      4       5
20080322 0010       0        0       0      0      27
```

The data missing some minutes (0002, 0006, 0007, 0008). I'm looking for a good way to insert the missing rows into the dataframe. What I've tried so far:

```
import pandas as pd
widths = [13,8,9,8,7,8]
df = pd.read_fwf("data", widths=widths)

df['date_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_time'] , format='%Y%m%d %H%M')
df = df.set_index('date_time').reindex(pd.date_range("20080322 0000", "20080322 0010", freq='1min').strftime('%Y%m%d %H%M'), fill_value="NaN")
print (df)
```

The missing rows appear, but all values are NaN. Any ideas?

Comment: *but all values are NaN* what values do you want?

Comment: @splash58 the integer values in the dataframes (f.e. 0,0,0,0,-11 in the first row)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is remove converting to datetimes and reindex by strings (created by [`DatetimeIndex.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.strftime.html)):

```
df = pd.read_fwf("data", widths=widths)

df = (df.set_index('date_time')
        .reindex(pd.date_range("20080322 0000", "20080322 0010", freq='1min')
        .strftime('%Y%m%d %H%M')))
print (df)
               var1  var2  var3  var4  var6
20080322 0000   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0 -11.0
20080322 0001   0.0   5.0   0.0   0.0   9.0
20080322 0002   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
20080322 0003   5.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
20080322 0004   0.0   0.0  11.0   0.0  -9.0
20080322 0005   0.0  12.0   0.0   0.0   1.0
20080322 0006   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
20080322 0007   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
20080322 0008   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
20080322 0009   7.0   0.0   0.0   4.0   5.0
20080322 0010   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  27.0
```

---

Another solutions is remove `strftime` for convert datetimes to strings so reindex by datetimes:

```
df = pd.read_fwf("data", widths=widths)

df['date_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_time'] , format='%Y%m%d %H%M')
df = (df.set_index('date_time')
        .reindex(pd.date_range("20080322 0000", "20080322 0010", freq='1min')))
```

Or use [`DataFrame.asfreq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.asfreq.html) - working with `DatetimeIndex`:

```
df = pd.read_fwf("data", widths=widths)

df['date_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_time'] , format='%Y%m%d %H%M')
df = df.set_index('date_time').asfreq('1 Min')
```

---

```
print (df)
                     var1  var2  var3  var4  var6
2008-03-22 00:00:00   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0 -11.0
2008-03-22 00:01:00   0.0   5.0   0.0   0.0   9.0
2008-03-22 00:02:00   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
2008-03-22 00:03:00   5.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
2008-03-22 00:04:00   0.0   0.0  11.0   0.0  -9.0
2008-03-22 00:05:00   0.0  12.0   0.0   0.0   1.0
2008-03-22 00:06:00   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
2008-03-22 00:07:00   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
2008-03-22 00:08:00   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
2008-03-22 00:09:00   7.0   0.0   0.0   4.0   5.0
2008-03-22 00:10:00   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  27.0
```

Last if necessary original format of `index` add [`DatetimeIndex.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.strftime.html):

```
df.index = df.index.strftime('%Y%m%d %H%M')
print (df)
               var1  var2  var3  var4  var6
20080322 0000   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0 -11.0
20080322 0001   0.0   5.0   0.0   0.0   9.0
20080322 0002   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
20080322 0003   5.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
20080322 0004   0.0   0.0  11.0   0.0  -9.0
20080322 0005   0.0  12.0   0.0   0.0   1.0
20080322 0006   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
20080322 0007   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
20080322 0008   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
20080322 0009   7.0   0.0   0.0   4.0   5.0
20080322 0010   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  27.0
```

Comment: Ok. Is it possible to keep the original data types (in this case int?) Now it is float.

Comment: @mcatis - Yes, it is possible if use `pandas 0.24.+` with [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25/user_guide/integer_na.html) - use `df = df.astype('Int64')`

Comment: thx it work's. do you know why my header "date_time" disappeared?

Comment: @mcatis - yop, because no parameter `name` in `date_range` - so for avoid it use `.reindex(pd.date_range("20080322 0000", "20080322 0010", freq='1min', name='date_time')))`

Comment: it doesn't work. although I've added the name paramter

Comment: @mcatis if not working use `df = df. rename_axis('date_time')` after my solution.

Comment: okay, "date_time" appear, but in extra row under the header. he also says that is one column less than the original dataframe. seems like the "date_time"-column is "segregated"?

Comment: @mcatis - it means it is index, for columns use `df = df.reset_index()`